# Java alternative of bad looking if-else or switch constructions

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Looking for modern way to realise String translation to replace bad looking if-else or switch constructions:

```
if ("UK".equals(country)) 
     name = "United Kingdom";
  if ("GE".equals(country))
     name = "Germany";
  if ("FR".equals(country))
     name = "France";
  if ("IT".equals(country))
     name = "Italy";
  [...]
```

or

```
switch (country) {
      case "UK": name = "United Kingdom"; break;
      case "GE": name = "Germany" break;
      case "FR": name = "France"; break;
      case "IT": name = "Italy" break;
  [...]
```

Comment: What is wrong with `switch`?

Comment: In switch statement you need to be careful about break; statements that aren't actually checked by the compiler. I don't think it's safe not evaluate it until
runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use java.util.Map.
create static countries variable.

```
private static final String UK = "UK";
private static final String GE = "GE";
private static final String FR = "FR";
private static final String IT = "IT";

private static final Map<String, String> COUNTRIES;
static {
    final Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<>();
    countries.put(UK, "United Kingdom");
    countries.put(GE, "Germany");
    countries.put(FR, "France");
    countries.put(IT, "Italy");
    COUNTRIES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(countries);
}
```

then can use "get" property from java.util.Map to get the country name

```
System.out.println(COUNTRIES.get(UK));
System.out.println(COUNTRIES.get(GE));
System.out.println(COUNTRIES.get(FR));
System.out.println(COUNTRIES.get(IT));
```

Answer (score 15):

You might want an `enum`.

```
public enum Country {
    UK("United Kingdom"),
    GE("Germany"), // sure this isn't DE?
    FR("France");
    // and so on
    private String countryName;
    private Country(String n) { countryName = n; }

    public String getCountryName() { return countryName; }
}
```

Now you can

```
Country c = Country.valueOf(countryString); // throws exception when unknown
name = c.getCountryName();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest approach would be inheritance and introduce some simple data structure to your code to represent this kind of information. This will stop your switches from escalating when extending your code. Let's have an abstract base class `Country` which provides some attributes like 'Name'. The name will never change and is specific to the type. So we define a class `UK` that inherits from `Country`. Now you can make use of polymorphism and iterate all countries of type `Country` and retrieve its name by accessing the (read-only) attribute 'Name' without any switches or type casts. When a new country is added you won't have to touch this kind of statements any more.

```
List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
countries.Add(new UK());
countries.Add(new Italy());

for (Country country : countries) 
{
  String countryName = country.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility is with HashMap:

```
private final Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<String, String>() {
  {
     put("UK", "United Kingdom");
     put("GE", "Germany");
     put("FR", "France");
     put("IT", "Italy");
     [...]
  }
};

name = countries.get(county);
```